# Get historical USB usage using terminal

Tags: macos, usb

I need to see historical USB usage on my mac.
I've tried

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep "Serial Number" -B5
```

but this only shows current.
Is there a command that shows historical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that type of data is not stored on the Mac by default.